# how to display only right page using booklet plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Is it possible to display only the right page using booklet ? I like the effect with flipping page, but I can only have displayed in page.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  I got this working simply by modifying the css.

I think it was a combination of `position: absolute; right:100%;` with css clip or css crop, or something like`clip: rect(10px,10px,10px,10px);`.

It basically still uses the same two page book, but hides your left page out of visible sight.
I found it quite neat to just show 10-15 px of the left page to make it look more book like.

Comment: can you please elaborate more,i am having the same problem